# Right turn signal in Pennsylvania - can I turn on red?

Tags: usa, driving, pennsylvania

I am travelling in Pennsylvania, USA, and I come across this sign:
[image: http://www.trafficsign.us/650/reg/r10-10r.gif]

Intersections here often have three sets of traffic lights, one with left turn signal signs, one with right turn signal signs, and one with none.

All of the lights in the intersection are the standard 3 light variety. The green light is either a standard circle or an arrow. It is NOT the type with a green light and a red arrow. There are no signs that say "No turn on Red".

Can I turn right on red?

Comment: +1 I've always wondered this and was surprised to find it was about my home state! Do other states not use these signs?

Comment: NY does not. In the event that there is a time when you can turn right but not go straight, we have a red light and a green arrow. On a dedicated left turn, we may have a traffic light with red, yellow, and green left turn arrows. Other lanes ignore it because its an arrow (even the red)

Comment: Ah okay, and I know in NJ this problem is mostly irrelevant due to jug handles, and I've never noticed it in DE. Hm, seems more confusing than anything. I've definitely not turned at intersections with these signs because I was unsure.

Comment: And the jug handles confused me when I first drove in NJ.  That's one of the downsides of the structure of the USA.  Every state does things a bit different.

Comment: You should try a roundabout... Weekend drivers from New York City completely freak out when they see one...  The sign is actually mostly useless.

Comment: I lived in Italy for a year.  Roundabouts are second nature.

Comment: I have witnessed many people not turning at a red light when it is
A right turn signal. Seems it just confuses people. We should just get rid of them. I do not see a point to them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Pennsylvania Driver's Manual](http://www.dmv.state.pa.us/pdotforms/pa_driversmanual/chapter_2.pdf)

> When there is a STEADY RED LIGHT, you must stop before crossing the marked stop line or
>   crosswalk. If you do not see any lines, stop before entering the intersection. Wait for a green light before you start.
>
> You may turn right while the light is red, unless a NO TURN ON RED sign is posted at the intersection.
>   You must first stop, check for and yield to pedestrians and other traffic.
>
> You may also turn left after you stop at a red light, if you are in the left lane and are turning left from a one-way street onto another one-way street, unless a sign tells you not to turn. You must first stop and yield to pedestrians and other traffic.

And additionally

> Although not common in Pennsylvania, a RED ARROW is used in other states. It means you may not turn in the direction the arrow points.

The sign you posted:

> **RIGHT TURN SIGNAL**
>   This sign is posted close to a traffic signal to indicate that the signal controls right turn movements.

In practice this usually means that there are situations when it is possible to turn right but not go straight.

There is also [DMV Guide to Young Drivers](http://www.dmv.state.pa.us/pdotforms/young_drivers/tutorsguide.pdf) which states:

> Making right turns at intersections with lights or signs:
>
> - Even when the light is green, look out for traffic turning left
>     from the oncoming lane.
> - Unless there’s a sign that says “No Turn on Red,” in
>     Pennsylvania it’s legal to turn right even on a red light after
>     coming to a complete stop – but only if there’s no traffic coming
>     from the left or across the street, or pedestrians in
>     the crosswalk.

So if you need to make a right turn on Red and there are no specific prohibitions you can do it in PA.

Comment: Interesting...  Downvote with no comments...

Comment: If I understand correctly, this "Although not common in Pennsylvania, a RED ARROW is used in other states. It means you may not turn in the direction the arrow points." implies that you might (though I guess really rarely) see a right-directed red arrow, as opposed to a simple red stop. I would see that as being an over-riding instruction **not** to turn while that red arrow is displayed.

Comment: @djna Correct.  The RED ARROWs I've seen for right turns usually had a sign "No TURN ON RED" as well. LIke PA-33 to PA-611 South

Answer (score 10):

**Yes, unless another sign forbids it.** [The sign is there to let you know there will be a turn arrow exclusively for you. It does not disallow right on red.](http://articles.mcall.com/2010-05-17/news/all-mc-warrior-hartzell.7272989may17_1_signal-head-uniform-traffic-control-devices-turn) If there is not a sign that says "No turn on red" or "No turns," you may turn right on red.

Answer (score 2):

One "gotcha" with some intersections that have a separate right turn signal is that the light may cycle green, yellow, red along with the main intersection and then quickly turn green again if/when the cross traffic from the right gets a green arrow.  No matter how short the red interval, such a light must be treated very differently from one which simply stays green.  If a car becomes entitled to the right of way while the light is green, it will retain that entitlement as long as the light remains green.  Once the light turns yellow, unless passage through the intersection is imminent, the car must yield right of way to on-coming traffic and continue to do so--*even if the light turns green again*--until all such traffic has cleared the intersection.

Comment: I have difficulty comprehending your answer and its relevance to the question.

Comment: The style of intersection to which I believe the OP is referring to frequently has one right-turn green interval which coincides with the 'ahead' light, and a separate right-turn-green interval which is only for the right turn.  I thought it important for readers who are unfamiliar with such intersections to be aware that even if the green intervals are very close together, the red interval between them is very important; someone who sees the light goes red and quickly green should watch out for a possible on-coming left turn in front of them.

Comment: Which has to do with the way that the "right on red" is performed with the yield to oncoming traffic but this has nothing to do with whether the "right on red" is allowed when a sign in the question is present as is the question

Comment: The intersections in question do NOT have a separate cycle for right turn only.  For instance, there is a T intersection that I go through daily.  The top of the T is always green.  When a car travelling through the bottom of the T triggers the light, the top of the T goes red, and then the traffic entering the top of the T gets a left green arrow (with a "Left Turn Signal" sign) and a right arrow (with a "Right Turn Signal" sign).

I wonder why they don't just use a single green light?

Comment: @MikeChristiansen: Your directions are a little vague; you are assuming an easy-west crossbar that matches the end of a north-south road?  In that scenario, call the east end E, west and W, and south end S, and describe traffic flows beast upon the point from they enter and their departure, a light could allow EW and WE, or allow EW, ES, SE, and possibly WS, or allow EW, WS, and SW.  Perhaps the lights aren't programmed to use all those states, but they could be.  The style of intersection I was thinking of...

Comment: ...may be found at the intersection of Illinois route 59 and North Aurora Road in Naperville, IL; I've heard of other examples elsewhere.  That has a separate right-turn signal which does indeed get two green intervals per cycle, and I've read people complaining of getting red-light tickets in the interval between the greens.  Attempted right turn on reds entering 59 from the west could hit left-turning traffic coming from the east when that traffic has a left arrow, but there's enough traffic from a train station to the west that it needs to flow at other times when the main light is red.

Comment: @supercat: The intersection I was initially referring to is Fisherville Rd & Reeceville Rd, Coatesville, PA.  (Image: http://i58.tinypic.com/16blhqa.png) - Since StreetSide went through there, this sign has been added.

Comment: However, this sign is all over the place in the Philadelphia area.

Comment: In this intersection (from the vantage point in the screenshot I posted), both lights are always the same.  There is never a right green and a left red.

Comment: @MikeChristiansen: When can traffic from the east turn south?  Does it ever get a green arrow, or does it just get a solid green and always have to yield to on-coming traffic?  Are U-turns from the east heading back to the east common, rare, or forbidden?  When traffic from the east has a left-turn arrow, traffic from the south could safely proceed to the east with no interference from any path except U-turning traffic from the east, so that might be a good time to light the right-turn arrow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13343/discussion-between-mike-christiansen-and-supercat)

Comment: Its legal to go through yellow lights, you do not have to yield (unless of course it would turn red before you entered the intersection).

Comment: @Andy: Vehicles that will be in an intersection when their light turns red have a duty to clear the intersection as quickly as possible.  Other vehicles thus have a duty to avoid unnecessarily delaying their ability to do so.

Comment: @supercat Ok, I don't see how that invalidates anything I said in my comment.  And why are you tagging me in a 5 year old question anyway?